# How to run xeyes in Docker Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, macos, debian, x11, x11-forwarding

My goal is to do X11 forwarding. The first step is to make sure xeyes works. However, when I tried to run xeyes, it throws error

The command

```
(base) jason@Jasons-Mac-mini darkmark-docker-web % docker run -it --rm --net=host -e DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority  my-xeyes
Error: Can't open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.abcde/org.xquartz:0
```

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      x11-apps \
      && rm -rf /usr/share/doc/* && \
      rm -rf /usr/share/info/* && \
      rm -rf /tmp/* && \
      rm -rf /var/tmp/*

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
USER user
CMD xeyes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it two ways. I use `alpine` but it is still X11 provided via XQuartz.

Both methods tested with:

- macOS Ventura 13.1
- Docker Desktop 14.6.2
- XQuartz 2.8.2

---

This one needs `socat`:

```
# Install socat and XQuartz
brew install socat
brew cask install xquartz

socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\" &

# Ensure XQuartz and docker are started - you can do this graphically too
open -a XQuartz
open -a docker

# Run alpine latest
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 alpine:latest

# Inside docker container. Install and run xeyes
/ # apk update && apk add xeyes && xeyes
```

---

This one doesn't need `socat`:

```
# Start XQuartz - could equally do it with Spotlight Search
open -a XQuartz

Goto XQuartz->Settings->Security and check "Authenticate Connections" and "Allow connections from network clients"

Stop and restart XQuartz - wait till it is running

xhost + $(hostname)
MarkBookPro.local being added to access control list

# Start alpine image
docker run --rm  -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 -it alpine

# Inside docker container. Install and run xeyes
/ # apk update && apk add xeyes && xeyes
```

Comment: I tried the first and second solution. None of them works. The second solution throws an error ```(base) jason@Jasons-Mac-mini ~ % xhost +$(hostname) xhost:  bad hostname "Jasons-Mac-mini.local"```

Comment: In the second method, try replacing the `xhost` command with plain `xhost +` It is a security vulnerability but if you are just testing on your local home network behind a router it is fine.

Comment: Do you know how to only allow docker container? `xhost +` and `DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0` does the job. But again, I am afraid of the security vulnerability as I use office wifi.

Comment: You can try `xhost + 127.0.0.1` which only allows connections originating from your local machine.