# How to enable X forwarding from Docker on ubuntu to Mac

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, x11-forwarding

My laptop is MAC. And I am developing on Ubuntu connecting remotely by ssh from my MAC.
I installed XQuartz on my MAC and now I am using X forwarding by adding -X option on ssh command. i.e. *ssh -X <user_name>@<ip_address>*
It works for me. for instance, if I executed `xeyes` on ubuntu, eyes can be seen on my MAC.
But when I tried to show eyes that is executed on docker on ubuntu, it NOT work.
The result of execution is as below: No error message but nothing shown.

```
$ docker compose up -d 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container docker-compose-test-test-1  Started   0.0s
```

yaml is as below:

```
services:
  test:
    image: xeyes_container
    tty: true
    command: xeyes
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

Of course, when I log into the ubuntu with rdp etc. and execute `docker compose` command, eyes can be seen.
But it is kind of troublesome for me to log into ubuntu with rdp etc. So I would like to see output on my MAC by using X forwarding.
Thank you so much for your all support!!

Comment: Maybe you can adapt from here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389081/2836621

Comment: Thank you but the link is for docker on mac, right? in my case, development pc is ubuntu and docker works on ubuntu. I confirmed `xeyes` here can be seen on ubuntu. my laptop is mac and what i want to do is I would like to see `xeyes` on mac by connecting docker via ubuntu. in this case, I guess x forward have to be done two time(docker -> ubuntu -> mac) but i do not have the idea how to do that. of course, other than x forward if there is any way to realize what i want to do, it is very welcome. the link you shared can help me do what i want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this on mac :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build image xeyes-image on ubuntu-machine
ssh ubuntu-machine docker build -t xeyes-image -f - . << EOF
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt install -y x11-apps xauth
EOF

# Run image on ubuntu-machine
ssh -X -T ubuntu-machine bash << 'EOF'
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY"
IFS=:. read _ port _ <<< $DISPLAY
echo "port=$port"
xauth=$(xauth list|awk '$1 ~ /.*unix:'$port'$/{print$3}')
echo "xauth=$xauth"
docker run --network=host -e DISPLAY --rm -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority-original xeyes-image bash -c "cp /root/.Xauthority-original /root/.Xauthority; xauth add $DISPLAY . $xauth; xeyes"
EOF
```

Calling method :

1. Copy/paste above script into test.sh
2. Run `bash test.sh`

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work for me with `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Error: Can't open display: <XXXXXX>:10.0
` message. I guess this is because the output of `xauth list|awk '$1 ~ /.*unix:'$port'$/{print$3}'` is empty on my mac(I believe xauth line is evaluated on mac). Is there any command executed beforehand?
And if possible, could you elaborate on what is doing in `IFS=:. read _ port _ <<< $DISPLAY`?

Comment: `All the commands` (including `xauth list`) run on Ubuntu `except `the two ssh`. `IFS=:. read _ port _ <<< $DISPLAY` put `10` in the variable `port`.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried but not worked with same error(`X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Error: Can't open display: <XXXXXX>:10.0`). DISPLAY, port are xauth NOT empty. sorry for my misunderstand. Is there anything to be tried?

Comment: I loggined docker container. 
```# xauth list | grep XH23040046-L
XH23040046-L/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674
XH23040046-L/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  43bc61da24aaafe7976bf4e7b5e38759
XH23040046-L/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  463d44e73964686142ca67968e5b4cbe
XH23040046-L/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e7660e1070f3844972733c68ed04a52e
XH23040046-L/unix:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  008589700540dc6850511248d73a606b
```

Comment: `# xauth list | grep 73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674
XH23040046-L/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674
XH23XXXXXX:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674
` This could help something? here: `DISPLAY=XH23040046-L:10.0`, `xauth=73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674`

Comment: I put 3 `echo` in my updated code, can you post result ?

Comment: please find the below. `DISPLAY=XH23040046-L:10.0`, `port=10`, `xauth=73f361697edba5075649901b0f85a674`

Comment: I doubled checked, the script worked on MacOS/Sonoma. I added the calling method in the answer, can you try again ? Also, can you add your MacOS/XQuartz version ?

Comment: thank you for your continuous support. I tried but same result. MacOS version is macOS Ventura version 13.6.1 and XQuartz version is 2.8.5.